# Ngx-translate setTraslation missing translation in dynamic component

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I want to load dynamic component that defines its own translations, but still uses the same instance of TranslateService so that global language change events reach the dynamic component.

I am running in an issue which I think is bug, see this stackblitz for reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1ujje5

And related issue on github: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/834

Any advises how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the translations coming via http request override the translations set in the dynamic component. Answer provided by https://github.com/alexzuza in the linked github issue.

```
this.translate.getTranslation('en').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
  this.translate.setTranslation('en', {
    'DYNAMIC': 'I am dynamic component'
  }, true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the first loading of the i18n files in the assets has the shouldMerge set to false.
Waiting for those files to be loaded before loading the dynamic component works.

For that I just added a dumb translation in both en.json and fr.json :

```
"LOADING_TEST": "LOADED"
```

Then used this observable to detect that the translations are loaded :

```
this.translate.get('LOADING_TEST')
.pipe(filter(_ => _ != 'LOADED'), first());
```

[Here is the fork with this suggested solution.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50015765-1)

Comment: You are correct, tho I will post an answer which I think is a bit cleaner. That one was posted to the github issue.